# Output menu using dpm() and zone template

Tags: routes, theming

I am using dpm($variables) to output the array elements for the zone menu. How do I use what is provided to output the zone menu in my template file?

[image]

Comment: Is this to do with the Omega theme?  Where are you using the `dpm()` command?  In a preprocess function?  If so it looks like you have access to everything you need and probably just need to print or render() the relevant variable in the associated template.  Need more details to help!

Comment: Thanks for following up. I ended up just using the drupal devel themer module. I don't think using dpm was outputting what I needed. I was using dpm() in a template file. 

Now that I am using devel themer, I need to display secondary and tertiary menu items to the right of the parent items. Do you know how I should get started with this?

Comment: My follow up question on printing secondary/tertiary links can be found here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/146218/secondary-tertiary-links-next-to-parent-links