# Secondary & Tertiary links next to Parent links

Tags: routes, navigation

How can I print expandable secondary and tertiary links to the right of the parent? 
For mobile, the secondary and tertiary links will need to stack below the parent links. Below is an example of what I am looking to achieve.

[image]
Menu tree
[image]
Menu on front end

Comment: The menu pushes the content below it and becomes fixed on scroll. The height of the menu expands when the sub menus are opened. Therefore, I cannot absolutely position the sub menus that are on the right. How can I build the menus so that the secondary and tertiary menus of each active parent shows to the right.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the module [menu block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block). This module allows you to display certain levels of a menu considering the selected parent item.

Comment: Thanks for responding! I did look into the menu block module. It is still unclear how I can display submenus of secondary/tertiary items to the right of each parent item. 

The parent items will all be listed to the left. When a parent items is clicked should show sub menus of secondary and tertiary items.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the menu tree and how I need it to show on the front end.

Comment: YOu have to add a menu block (under structure) and configure that you only want to show the menu items starting on level 2. Then add another menu block only showing menu items on level 1. Expose them on your website and it all will magically work :)

Comment: Thanks but my issue is not with using menu block. But rebuilding the template to display the menu blocks a certain way.